# Using range to display numbers in a interval

Tags: python, range

I'm very new to python and I've just been trying some simple programs, I'm currently trying to make a program that shows all even numbers in a interval that the user inputs. I have it working but I think I have a logic error which I can't figure out.
If I use the interval 2-8 my program will print

```
2
2
4
4
4
4
6
6
6
6
6
6
```

My code is:

```
startingnumber = int(input("Please enter a starting even number:"))
if startingnumber%2==0:
    endingnumber = int(input("Please enter an ending number:"))
else:
    print("Please eneter an even number")

for num in range(startingnumber,endingnumber):
        for i in range(num):
            if (num%2) ==0:
                print(num)
```

Could anyone try help to spot my mistake please?
Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason 2 is being displayed and 8 not (i.e. the interval is [2, 8[ ) or should it be [2, 8] so 8 being displayed also?

Comment: Ideally 8 should be displayed as well but I guess that will be my next task ;).

Comment: You can do that by adding 1 to endnumber

Comment: @muddyfish ah ok thankyou for the pointer

Comment: @Wadicus it's a work around but if it is a clean solution, is questionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for num in range(startingnumber,endingnumber):
            if (num%2) ==0:
                print(num)
```

You have an extra loop you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

```
Just use a step of 2:

range(start, end, step)

#This is not suggestible way to code in Python, but it gives a better understanding


numbers = range(1,10)

even = []

for i in numbers:

     if i%2 == 0:

       even.append(i)
print (even)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
for num in range(startingnumber,endingnumber):
```

do

```
for num in range(startingnumber+startingnumber%2,endingnumber+1,2):
    print(num)
```

Comment: That wont work. That assumes the user given character is even.

Comment: The OP is already doing (basic) checks to see if the input is even. `for i in range(1,6,2):print i` does indeed print `1,3`. If they wanted to output `1,3,5` they would have to add 1 to the end number

Comment: @muddyfish The OP wrote that he wanted the EVEN numbers.